# Is there a way to show a TypeScript error when an unknown property is passed in an object to function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to force an error in TypeScript if an object passed into a function contains a property that doesn't exist on the set interface?

```
interface ITest {
  id: number
  name: string
}

const testFunc = (data: ITest) => {
  console.log(data)
}

const test = {id: 1, name: 'hello', test: ''}

testFunc(test) // is there a way to get this to throw an error to say that test does not belong to ITest?
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUIGczIN4BQyywAJgFzIgCuAtgEbRFVy0SU5SgDmBAvgQIIA9iBzJIOAGLUQCZAF5kAClJwwcShmxgAlIoB8+ZiLHCANhAB054d1Xq4u-oNPjJuJXjKUAjABoWNkoAcgALCHNbEMCPUJCBAg8ZOWUPfQB6DJIsCQioFDhkAHc4AE8JYWRuCFwwMOBcsCr6qGFi5DgQZGg2qErkLHK89QkdZFJhbCphXEZbEG4B7RwAfkEgA

Comment: maybe you can change the `type` of test to ITest - `const test: ITest = ...` this would throw an eroor.

Comment: Hey, [here is an straight forward working solution.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUIGczIN4BQyywAJgFzIgCuAtgEbRFVy0SU5SgDmBAvgQJgAngAcUGbGACiAD0RgAPOgB8yALzJ0yCLMghSWNJhzIA-MmZyEAG2qkIigNYRhAexhaANMhfvPkjhquvqGVBAAbtDmWsiUIJHR8YlQANyCCG4gppA4AGLUIAgayMpeagAUpHBgcJSBMvIISqoAlBpqhMSZ2W42EAB0Nm7cVTVwrfwZWTlSJXhklACMPiCs7MgA5AAWEDbDmz65YJSbmwI9pgDublBORpoLFMgrLGynu-tu5+mXuKRubAAOTcuEeixeAiEUgKRQqx3aAHpESQjGBdlAUHBkFc4MJkGA3MhuBBcOjgGiieioG4rsg4CAdFAaVACUSsHiCdsagS5gDsFRQchGMMQNw2cYpGZoflCggKjc7lhWuljrD5fysCCwCrBEA)